# Create column with x% values equal to y in r

Tags: r

I'd like to create a column of predetermined length n of values where x% of entries are 1, and the rest are 0. What is the most straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit on how you want to handle rounding when the percentage doesn't come out to an integer, but something like this should work:

```r
n <- 30
x <- 0.3
new_col <- c(rep(1, round(x * n)), rep(0, n - round(x * n)))
```

which returns a vector:

```r
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This could be added as a column to an existing data frame using `df$new_col <- c(rep(1, round(x * n)), rep(0, n - round(x * n)))`.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is the number of values, and `x` is the probability of 1, you could try the following using `rbinom` (binomial random variable generation) or `sample` to sample from 0 and 1.

```
n <- 30
x <- 0.3

set.seed(123)

rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = c(x, 1 - x))

[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1

sample(0:1, size = n, prob = c(1 - x, x), replace = TRUE)

[1] 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```